# Das Verb - anrechnen

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Beispiel: Das Auto wurde Ihnen mit 5.000 Euro angerechnet.

5.000 Euro bezieht sich auf das alte Auto (der Händler hat es auf diesen Preis geschätzt) oder 5.000 Euro ist der Betrag, der vom Kaufpreis des neuen Autos abgezogen werden kann (z.B. Preis des alten Autos - 10.000 Euro, Preis des neuen Autos - 15.000 Euro; 15.000 - 10.000 = 5.000)?

Comment: Es ist nicht falsch, bei Zahlen ein Leerzeichen als Tausendertrennzeichen zu verwenden, aber wenn du das machst, kann es passieren, dass genau an einer solchen Stelle ein Zeilenumbruch entsteht. Dann steht von der Zahl 5 000 die Ziffer 5 am Ende einer Zeile, und 000 steht am Beginn der nächsten (genau das ist in deinem Posting passiert). Daher habe ich diese Leerzeichen durch die in Europa üblichen Punkte ersetzt. Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49204/in-germany-commas-are-used-as-decimal-separators-in-numbers-so-what-character/50276#50276

Comment: Text und Beispielrechnung klaffen auseinander. Der farblich hinterlegte Satz passt jedenfalls nicht zur letzten Rechnung, in der 10.000 abgezogen werden. 5000 können abgezogen werden, nicht 10000.

Answer (score 4):

*Angerechnet* means the value for the old car has already been subtracted from the price of the new car.

In general *anrechnen* means to include one transaction into another.

So the long version:
"Das neue Auto kostet 15 000 €. Führ Ihr altes Auto können wir Ihnen 5 000 € anbieten. Wenn wir das alte Auto anrechnen bleiben also noch 10 000 €"

So in "Das Auto wurde Ihnen mit 5.000 Euro angerechnet." The price has been reduced by 5000€. "mit x angerechnet" means "reduced by x"

Comment: Warum antwortest du in einer Fremdsprache, wenn die Frage doch auf Deutsch gestellt wurde? Dies hier ist ein Forum, das die deutsche Sprache zum Inhalt hat. Lina gibt in ihrem Profil zwar nicht viel über sich preis, hat aber bisher alle Fragen in fehlerfreiem Deutsch gestellt. Sie beherrscht die Sprache also auf einem einigermaßen hohen Level. Und du selbst scheinst auch deutscher Muttersprachler zu sein. Warum also schreibst du die Antwort in einer Fremdsprache?

Comment: Und das ändert sich nicht dadurch, dass es in der Frage lautet "mit x Euro angerechnet"?

Comment: Hallo Hubert, Mein Verständnis ist das dies hier ein öffentliches Forum auf einer englischsprachigen Web Seite ist. Vielleicht gibt es hier also Leute die deutsch lernen wollen und diese Information nützlich finden, denen es aber leichter fällt wenn die Antwort selbst nicht in der zu erlernenden Sprache formuliert ist. Auf deutsch.stackexchange.de würde ich dir aber völlig zustimmen.

Comment: @LarsPötter: Dises Argument lese ich ziemlich häufig. Aber was veranlasst dich zu glauben, dass z.B. Russen, Italiener, Araber oder Chinesen, die Deutsch lernen wollen, bereits Englisch können? Die gemeinsame Sprache aller, die diese Seite besuchen, ist Deutsch, nicht Englisch. Wer ein Deutsch-Forum besucht, möchte Deutsch lernen, nicht Englisch.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast Die meisten Fragen hier sind in englisch formuliert. Wer kein englisch kann der wird hier nur wenig finden, außerdem bekommt er/sie Probleme mit der Navigation auf der Seite. Wenn ich eine Sparache lernen will und Fragen habe dann möchte ich die am liebsten in einer Sprache beantwortet bekommen die ich schon kann. Für Besucher dieser Seite ist die Sprache die sie bereits können englisch, auch bei  Russen, Italiener,.. die sich hier Ihre Informationen holen um deutsch zu lernen. Und das du diese Aussage "ziemlich häufig" liest ist vielleicht ja ein Indiz dafür das es stimmt.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn etwas angerechnet wird, bedeutet das, dass du eigentlich eine bestimmte Leitung erbringen musst, aber die Möglichkeit hast, einen Teil dieser geforderten Leistung auf einem anderen Weg als ursprünglich vorgesehen zu erbringen.

Studenten müssen, um ihr Studium abschließen zu können, Prüfungen über bestimmte Fächer ablegen. Einige Studenten haben davor aber möglicherweise ein anderes Studium absolviert, und haben bereits dort vieles gelernt, was im aktuellen Studium auf dem Lehrplan steht. In so einem Fall können sie sich das eine oder andere Fach des aktuellen Studiums **anrechnen** lassen.

Das heißt: Sie müssten eigentlich eine bestimmte Leistung erbringen, die z.B. darin besteht, das Fach Orchideenzucht zu belegen und dann darüber eine Prüfung ablegen. Wenn eine Studentin aber nachweisen kann, dass sie davor schon Orchideen gezüchtet hat, kann die Studiengangsleitung beschließen, dass sie dieses Fach nicht absolvieren muss. Ihr wird das Fach Orchideenzucht **angerechnet.**

Beim Autokauf ist es dasselbe: Du musst eigentlich eine bestimmte Leistung erbringen um das Auto zu bekommen, du musst nämlich einen bestimmten Preis dafür bezahlen (angenommen 15.000,00 Euro). Du hast aber bereits ein altes Auto, das du verkaufen willst. Der Händler würde dir das alte Auto abkaufen, aber nur, wenn du das neue Auto bei ihm kaufst. Und dafür bietet er dir 5.000 Euro. Diese 5.000 Euro zahlt er dir aber nicht aus. Er zieht sie vom Preis des neuen Autos ab. Er **rechnet** dir also den Wert des alten Autos **an.**

Deine Frage, ob mit den 5.000 Euro der geschätzte Wert des alten Autos, oder der Preisnachlass vom neuen gemeint ist, läuft also darauf hinaus, dass beides dasselbe ist. Das alte Auto ist 5.000 Euro wert, und dieser Wert wird an den Kaufpreis des neuen Autos **angerechnet,** also von der eigentlich zu erbringenden Leistung abgezogen.

Comment: Seine letzte Beispielrechnung deutet aber darauf hin, dass er meint, im zweiten Beispiel mit gleichem Auto und Autohändler wären die 5000 der Preis, der nach dem Anrechnen übrigbleibt. Sicher bin ich da aber nicht.

Comment: Ich habe meinem post erweitert um zu erklären das es "reduced by" ist und nicht "reduced to". @Hubert: Da fehlt ein "s in dem ersten mal Leistung. Da ein edit aber mindestens 6 Zeichen haben muß kann ich das nicht editieren. Hast Du eigentlich kein ß auf deiner Tastatur oder ist das alles mit der neuen Rechtschreibung so abgeändert worden?